# Keep all variables after every iteration

Tags: r, github, github-api

Using the following snippet it is possible to iterate two api call in json format

At the end of the loop there is a command with transforms json to data frame

How is it possible to keep in every iteration all these variables and fill NA if a value in the specific variable does not exist in a specific iteration?

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httpuv)
library(httr)

myapp <- oauth_app(appname = "insert_your_credentials",
                   key = "insert_your_credentials",
                   secret = "insert_your_credentials")

github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"), myapp)


gtoken <- config(token = github_token)

df <- data.frame(link = c("https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=%22image%22+AND+%22covid%22?page=1&per_page=100", "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=%22image%22+AND+%22covid%22?page=2&per_page=100"))


for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

    req <- GET(df$link[i])
    
    # Extract content from a request
    json1 = content(req)
      
      # Convert to a data.frame
  
    char <- rawToChar(req$content)
    dfcollection <- jsonlite::fromJSON(char)
    
}
```

Comment: You can wrap with `tryCatch` and specify to return `NA` when there are errors

Comment: @akrun please could you give an example for this?

Comment: Try the code posted.  With your example 'df', it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It may be wrapped with `tryCatch` or `possibly` from `purrr`.  Below code uses `possibly`

```
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)
convertToJSON <- function(x)
{
     req <- GET(x)
    
        # Extract content from a request
        json1 = content(req)
      
          # Convert to a data.frame
  
        char <- rawToChar(req$content)
        dfcollection <- jsonlite::fromJSON(char)
        return(dfcollection)
    }
pconvertToJSON <- possibly(convertToJSON, otherwise = NA)
out <- map(df$link, pconvertToJSON)
```

Comment: the out is not a dataframe and the output should have 200 rows if run the example df